dataclasses for ORM models in SQLAlchemy
I am trying to define a dataclass for my model in the same class of the model, where i have defined the table.
this is my model class,
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from Database.db_setup import Base


@dataclass
class Director(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'directors'

    id: int = field(init=False, default=None)
    name: str

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)



this is my gateway class where i am trying to use it
from src.Database.db_setup import Session
from src.Database.directors.director_model import Director
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


def add_director(director_data: Director):
    session = Session()
    new_director = Director(name=director_data.name)
    try:
        session.add(new_director)
        session.commit()
        print(f"Added Director '{director_data.name}' successfully.")
    except IntegrityError:
        print(f"Error adding director: Director with name {director_data.name} already exists.")
        session.rollback()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error adding director: {e}")
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()


tempdirector = Director("Jerry")
add_director(tempdirector)


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/student-4318/src/Database/directors/gateway.py", line 23, in 
temdirector = Director("Jerry")
TypeError: init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
I am getting this error message , how can i ignore the id as an positional argument because it gets generated by itself.

def init(self, name: str):
self.name = name
adding this function fixed the problem

The recommended way to integrate dataclasses with ORM is to use the MappedAsDataclass mixin:
# fmt: off
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, MappedAsDataclass, Session, mapped_column
# fmt: on

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    """ORM objects implemented as DataClasses"""


class Director(Base):
    __tablename__ = "directors"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False, unique=True)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as sess:
    me = Director(name="Gord")
    sess.add(me)
    sess.commit()
    print(me)  # Director(id=1, name='Gord')

